# M2 - Method to automatically include module css?

Tags: magento2, module, css, less

I am trying to avoid adding a head tag for every module I create. The other method of doing it via design css files would be that they depend on each other then and are no longer separated - that is unacceptable to me.

I have seen a _module.less file, I was hoping this would be automatically included upon less generation?

Comment: This link might be helpful for you https://mage2.pro/t/topic/34

Comment: I'm sorry but it isn't.